# Can you wire a breaker directly to an extension cable?

Tags: inverter, mains, cables

I have a modular UPS system, it provides power from mains or inverter depending on which is available. The power is provided to one short extension cable to which appliances are connected.

For safety, and to prevent drawing too much current (which could damage the automatic transfer switch, or inverter, or batteries), I want to connect a breaker inline with the extension cable.

Can this be done?

My plan is to cut open the extension cable, wire the live wire through the breaker, insulate the wire and breaker (in a plastic box) to prevent any chance of electric shock.

Comment: Re, "in a plastic box." The reason why building codes require junctions to be enclosed in boxes is for fire prevention. Faulty junctions can get hot. If you use a plastic box, be sure to use a box that won't easily catch fire.

Comment: P.S., Are you sure that your UPS doesn't already have some form of over-current protection? Every UPS that I have ever owned\* had a built in circuit breaker. \[\* But, I have never owned one with the form factor that you describe.]

Comment: A modular UPS is a UPS comprised of Indvidual parts forming a whole UPS, so imagine an inverter, batteries, chargers, automatic inverter transfer switch all connected together.  If I want a circuit breaker, I need to add one. Also, the circuit breaker is not only there to protect the inverter, but also protect the automatic transfer switch (as it has rated watts it can operate at) and the batteries (from being drained above their C20 discharge rate).

Answer (score 2):

Rather than try to make your own inline breaker, why not just buy one. There are several listed on line. There are problems with making your own.

- If it is going to be used outdoors or anywhere near water it needs to
  be sealed, can you guarantee you can do this?
- The cost of the component parts and your time building it would probably exceed that of buying one.
- This is a safety critical component, Do you know exactly what you are doing? With all due respect, if you have to ask here, you appear not to. Sorry, but nobody here will give you advice on DIY safety equipment as they won't take the responsibility if you get it wrong.
- The design may also depend on the layout of the equipment. Is the UPS remote from the appliances? Could you mount a breaker alongside the UPS and the transfer switch rather than inline?

Comment: They are not readily available in my country of residence. I could import a plug with a breaker at the specific amperage I am looking for, but the costs will be higher than simply adding one into the circuit myself.